# Can traffic be routed through browser VPN extensions?

Tags: google-chrome, vpn, firewall, routing

The firewall in my college can block openVPNs, several websites and gaming related apps like STEAM. But I can access all the blocked sites by using VPN extensions which have been added to chrome. I wanted to know if there is way to send all my computer traffic through the VPN extensions (like zenmate etc) of the browser.

Thnx.

Answer (score 0):

The people at [VPNBOOK](http://www.vpnbook.com/) have an openVPN section with 4 certificates to connect to each of the servers available - try both the "tcp" and "udp" options, port 443 is the most likely to work as it the port used for encrypted HTTPS traffic - use of a VPN should be very hard to detect over this port. Try all the available certificates for the server of your choice, while it *is* possible to block openVPN its is a very difficult thing to do, so its unlikely your college would have gone to the effort of doing this.

The "certificates" are configuration files, so place them in the "config" folder of your openVPN installation.